# LatexIt compile very slow

Tags: latexit

Is it possible to increase the compile speed for LatexIt? It takes about 5 second for me to compile, even for an empty document.

[image]

Comment: With a 2.7 GHz Intel Core I7 and 16GB RAM, it takes some seconds also for me. I don't think there's much to do.